# custom post type WYSIWG removes paragraphs when displayed

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-qtranslate

I have a WordPress 5.2.3 instance that is multilingual with the help of the [qtranslate-x](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/about/) plugin. I created a custom post type with a translatable WYSIWG field. The visual WYSIWG editor generally works, but when I display the content of the field on a page, the paragraphs are removed.

This is how it looks like in the editor:

[image]

This is how the page is rendered (direct link: https://crossroads-festival.org/de/film/your-turn):

[image]

As you can see, the paragraphs are lost when the field is displayed.

Interestingly, if I do the editing in HTML by using the text mode of the WYSIWG editor, the formatting does not get lost. However, this is not a solution, since my client wants to work with the visual editor.

I use the following plugins related to custom fields and translations. All are updated:

- [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)
- [Advanced Custom Fields: qTranslate](http://funkjedi.com/)
- [Custom Post Type UI](https://webdevstudios.com/)
- [qTranslate slug](http://github.com/not-only-code)
- [qTranslate-X](http://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/about)

I don't know how or where to exactly fix this issue. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I know that I should use the newly developed qtranslate-xt plugin, but for now this is not an option for me, so a solution (maybe quick & dirty) for now, would be satisfactory for me.